# How to check statistical validity of the k-means cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

In my MWE using the Iris dataset, my analysis found that there are two clusters in which the scaled iris data can be grouped into.

```
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
library(tidyverse)

scale(iris[1:4])%>% clusGap(FUN = kmeans,
                    nstart = 25, K.max = 10,
                    B = 50)%>%
fviz_gap_stat()

scale(iris[1:4])%>%
kmeans(nstart = 25, centers = 2)%>%
fviz_cluster(data=scale(iris[1:4]))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        plot.title = element_blank())
```

How to prove that the two clusters generated are statistically significant?

Comment: They are "significant". The `kmeans` function divides the observations according to their values. They will only not be significant if the sample size is very small. If you were to place buttons on a ruler and then define group one as the buttons on positions 1 - 6 and group 2 as the buttons on positions 7 - 12, there would obviously be a significant difference between the groups. You are doing exactly that with `kmeans`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worthwhile to illustrate this with an example:

```
dta <- matrix(rnorm(99), 33, 3)
grps <- kmeans(dta, 2)
summary(manova(dta~grps$cluster))
#              Df Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
# grps$cluster  1  0.729   26.004      3     29 2.284e-08 ***
# Residuals    31                                            
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Notice the highly significant results even though we are using random data. You cannot test the groups against the same variables that you used to define the groups in the first place. Each time you run these three lines you will get a new random sample. It will always be "significant."